# Update SLA Status

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need Help with DAX query, I have below data set

[image]

DAX

```
SLA_miss =
IF (
    [Task_Status] <> "Task Completed"
        && [Task_Status] <> "Cancelled"
        && Task_data[Status] = "History",
    IF (
        Task_data[Task_due_date_only] < TODAY (),
        "Breached",
        "Complete"
    ),
    "On track"
)
```

I want to write Dax query to track if SLA was missed.
If task due date is in past and Task status is "Cancelled" or "Task Completed" SLA miss should say "Complete" Else say "breached". If date is in future SLA miss should say "on track"

any idea?

Comment: After proper formatting you can hopefully see your problem yourself!

Comment: Sorry i am not good at DAX so not sure correct format's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about formats, it's about logic. Try this:

```
SLA Status = 
IF(
    Task_data[Task_due_date] >= TODAY(),
    "On track",
    IF(
        OR(
            Task_data[Task_Status] = "Task Completed",
            Task_data[Task_Status] = "Cancelled"
        ),
        "Complete",
        "Breached"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i have added another condition and its working now
SLA Status = 
IF(
    Task_data[Task_due_date] >= TODAY()&& Task_data[Task_Status]="Cancelled",
    "No Action",
    IF(
        OR(
            Task_data[Task_Status] = "Task Completed",
            Task_data[Task_Status] = "Cancelled"
        ),
        "Complete",
        "Breached"
    )
)